# Show console.log message with socket.io and Express.js on Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to see a `console.log` message without results from the socket when someone connects to application. Here is what i have on `/app.js` and `/bin/www` files:

> **Just a way to return a message on console for check if the socket works on**

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
// socket.io
var io = socket();
app.io = io;
// var for routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var projects = require('./routes/projects');
var messages = require('./routes/messages');
//socket message
io.on( "connection", function(socket){
    console.log( "A user connected" );
});
```

**www**

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('archiers:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);


/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
var server = http.createServer(app);

// socket.io

var io = app.io;
io.attach(server);
```

Comment: both of them you said can serve

Comment: i think that question is easy to understand, just a way to return a message on console for check if the socket works...

Comment: I can see that English is not your first language. I apologize if I am rude or abrupt.

Comment: i cannot see the message from the "log" on the terminal when i load the app.

Comment: Please open up the Console of your browser. The Console provides a log on the Browser side whereas `app.js` is on the Server. It may be that the Browser has not initiated a connection yet. The Browser's Console may reveal the errors. Are there any errors there?

Comment: i don't have any message. Nothing from server and nothing from Browser, first, i want at least to have a message from app.js now.

Comment: If you add a console.log line to the end of app.js then you will get a message from app.js when it is initialized.

Comment: i have this io.on( "connection", function(ssocket){
    console.log( "A user connected" );
}); on app.js and don't send anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111462/discussion-between-marcos-r-guevara-and-george-bailey).

Comment: Are you looking in your server console for the log? Not the browser console.

Comment: yes, i'm looking in the server console but nothing happens

Answer (score -2):

It would seem that you are working with some example code (rather than having written all of that yourself).

The example code you are using is quite a bit longer than it needs to be to accomplish your goals this early on.

1. For one thing your app.js is not "listening" on any port number - so it cannot possibly get a connection to work.
2. I can see your www js file would have to cause an error with process.env because the browser has no such variable.
3. Since you are not getting an error in your browser Console that means there must be a problem with the HTML file (which you have not posted thus far.
4. I expect there are other problems with the example code you are using that I have not seen.

Since you do not yet understand enough details of the code, I would suggest you start over.

You need to start with a smaller project.

Search the internet for a very small io.js example that *works* when you download and run it and go from there.

It will be much easier that way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12304794)

Comment: @KevinGuan, Reviewing the conversation I had with the OP, this is the ultimate correct answer for his situation. I've expanded my answer to clarify - how's this?

Comment: I would like to see suggestions for improvement instead of -1 votes. I think I was helpful to the OP. Do you think I have given poor advice?